# How to write assembler language - what do I need to get set up

Tags: assembly

I've read that learning a low level language can help writing higher level languages (although not essential).

However, I don't know how to get set up.

If some one said to me, "I want to learn VB.NET or C#.NET, how do I do it?" I would reply with: Get a PC with Windows OS, download .NET framework, download Visual Studio and here is a 'hello world' tutorial.

I have exactly the same question, but with an assembler language. I appreciate it may be different for each language, but I'm not precious about which language you choose to explain.

The reason for this, is I can run code natively on my machine but I get the feeling assembler is more about hardware and does that require an emulator or does it have to be done in live (where I need a piece of hardware to work on).

Comment: assembler is not so much about hardware as many folks want to believe.  I highly recommend using an instruction set simulator as it greatly increases your chances of success by greatly reducing your frustration  debugging.  Ultimately get the right hardware.  I strongly urge to not learn x86 first, learn it last or never.  Much better architectures are msp430 or pdp11, arm, thumb (skip thumb2 at first), avr, etc.  mips is a good choice as a second instruction set, I would learn two or three, they get exponentially easier to learn from one to the next.

Comment: the raspberry pi suggestion is a good one, please use the bare metal section of the forum for help as folks have had various issues with the baking pi tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent option you have is to buy a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) and follow this tutorial: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/

Another option is to buy this book: http://nostarch.com/hacking2.htm.  It comes with a LiveCD already setup for you to start tinkering, which you may download for free here: http://nostarch.com/hackingCD.htm

Happy hacking :)

EDIT:

A free ebook is here for 6502 assembly:  http://skilldrick.github.com/easy6502/

Comment: This is beyond perfect. Beers are on me for this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another fun one to play with is the MARS MIPS simulator. You don't need to purchase any extra hardware to run it, and it shows you what is happening in memory as you use it. Also, it's free.

Link [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/)

Answer (score 2):

With all the other answers you should be well on your way one thing I haven't noticed is example code or anything to help you start writing code.  Try out this link:
http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf

try this code:

```
a200 

Db"Hello World$"

A190

MOV DX,0200;    MOVE DX TO LOCATION WHERE THE STRING IS AT

MOV AH,09;  09 IS THE OUTPUT STRING SELECTION

INT 21; DOS SERICES...WRITING TO THE SCREEN

RET

a100

call 190; write the string starting at location 0200

int 3
```

I have not tested this code so if there are bugs....
happy coding!!!

Comment: So how do I run this code? As said in my OP I normally do all in VS as it can compile and debug etc. So where do I paste this code and how do I execute it? :)

Comment: how to copy and paste and run it: 1. take out the spaces between the a200 and db"hello world$" lines of code and paste them.  Then take out the spaces betweeen the code that is written between a190 and ret  copy and paste that .....do the same with a100 to int 3...copy and paste.  2  then to execute your code you will g=100 which simply means execute the code starting at 0100 memory location.